# Decomposition of rotational matrix using {$H, T$} only

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates

We know that {$H,T$} is universal. However, I don't understand how we can generate any rotational matrix from this set. For example, how can I build

\begin{bmatrix} 
    cos(\pi/8) & sin(\pi/8)\\
    -sin(\pi/8) & cos(\pi/8)
    \end{bmatrix}

Where does the $\pi/8$ come from? To me it seems like we can only build rotational matrices involving multiples of $\pi/4$ from this universal gate set

Comment: As a general rule, it's highly non-trivial and cannot be done exactly. You need to use a synthesis algorithm to find a high accuracy sequence that achieves the unitary that you want. (Side note: H and T and not universal. They are single-qubit universal. You need to add a two-qubit gate such as cNOT to make them universal)

Comment: @DaftWullie So the "universal" set is actually not universal?

Comment: Universal means that any gate can be approximated to arbitrary precision, not decomposed exactly. And what DaftWullie means is that $\{H, T\}$ is only universal for `single qubit` operations; you'll need to add, say, $CNOT$ to make the set universal for an arbitrary number of qubits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (asymptotically) far more efficient ways of performing the calculation than using the Solovay-Kitaev algorithm. I like the package provided [here](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/newsynth/), assuming your rotation can easily be related to a Z rotation (your example can).

Let's take your example of $e^{i Y \pi/8}$. First, I'm going to change basis to make this into a $Z$ rotation,
$$
e^{i Y \pi/8}=\sqrt{X}e^{i Z \pi/8}\sqrt{X}^\dagger=HSH e^{i Z \pi/8}HS^\dagger H
$$
(where $S=T^2$ and $S^\dagger=T^6$). Now we can run the gridsynth program to approximate a $\pi/4$ Z rotation:

```
gridsynth pi/4
```

and it gives the output

```
SHTSHTHTSHTSHTSHTHTSHTSHTSHTSHTHTHTHTSHTHTHTSHTHTSHTHTHTSHTSHTHTHTHTHTHTHTSHTSHTHTHTHTHTHTSHTHTHTHTSHTSHTHTSHTHTHTHTSHTHTHTSHTHTSHTHTHTSHTHTSHTSHTHTSHTSHTHTSHTHTSHTHTHTSHTHTSHTSHTHTSHTSHTSHTSHTHTHTHTHTSHTSHTHTHTSHTHTHTHTSHTHTHTSHTHTHTSHTSHTSHTHTSHTSHTSHTSHTHTHTHTSHTSHTHTSHTHTSHTSHTHTHTHTHTSHTSHTSHTSHTSHTHTSHTHTSHTHTSHX
```

which we insert in place of the $e^{iZ\pi/8}$, and should be accurate to $10^{-10}$.

Answer (score 2):

For single-qubit gates this can be done with the (indeed rather complex) Solovay-Kitaev algorithm. A solid pedagogical review is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030). I put a working implementation [here](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/main/src/solovay_kitaev.py) (it took me forever to get that to work ;-)

Note that for this algorithm to work, the rotations must be part of $SU(2)$ and have a determinant of 1. This means I had to convert the H, T gates via something like this:

```
def to_su2(u):
  return np.sqrt(1 / np.linalg.det(u)) * u

base = [to_su2(ops.Hadamard()), to_su2(ops.Tgate())]
```

So the algorithm is not strictly using H and T.